# How to get Phaser 3 timerEvent and methods to work properly? And get objects to already be instantiated when the game begins?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

The goal of my project is to make a tree planting game. When the game starts it should already have say, 10 trees in random positions as a starting point. Then, the duck can plant trees via moving with the cursor and planting with the spacebar. Every 1 second that passes, i want a random number of trees between 5-15 inclusive to destruct on their own. There will be a counter for the number of trees currently on screen and it updates every second. Game over when it hits 0.

**Here is what I have so far/planning on implementing:**

- Counter for the trees
- Duck moving and planting on canvas

**Here is what I'm having trouble with:**

- Getting the game to already start off with 10 trees.
- I am getting an error message that says that onEvent() method is not defined when it seems like it is in the code for destroying trees.

Here is my code so far, trying to implement the destruction of trees and I do not know how to instantiate the initial 10 trees :( :

As you can see, I've already tried fix the onEvent not defined error by putting it before i call the method but im still recieving the same error.

```
class Scene2 extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super("playGame");
    }
    //var timedEvent;
    onEvent(){
        for(var i = 0; i<2; i++){ 
            var tree = this.projectiles.getChildren()[i];
            tree.update();
        }
    }
    create(){    
        this.grass = this.add.tileSprite(0,0,config.width,config.height,'grass').setOrigin(0,0);
        
        //maybe add loops (and some updated sprites) for animals to move in place. i can learn that from one of gamedev acad's tutorials.
        this.ella = this.add.sprite(200, 400, "ella"); // later do random spots
        this.ella.play("ella_anim");
        this.ella.setScale(.45);
        
        this.tiger = this.add.sprite(500, 200, "tiger"); // later do random spots
        this.tiger.play("tiger_anim");
        this.tiger.setScale(.4);
        
        this.monkey = this.add.sprite(100, 100, "monkey"); // later do random spots
        this.monkey.play("monkey_anim");
        this.monkey.setScale(.4);
       
        this.duck =this.physics.add.sprite(200,300, "duck");
        var follower = this.duck.setDepth(100);
        follower.play("duck_anim");
        follower.setScale(.6);
        this.input.on('pointermove', function(pointer) 
        {
            this.physics.moveToObject(follower, pointer, 240);
            
        },this);
        follower.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
        //follower.setScale(.5);
        this.add.text(20,20, "Playing game", {font: "25px Arial", fill: "yellow"});
        
        this.spacebar = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SPACE);
        
       
        var timedEvent = this.time.addEvent({ delay: 1000, callback: onEvent, callbackScope: this, loop: true });
        this.projectiles = this.add.group(); //holds all the trees
    }
    
    update(){
        text.setText('Event.progress: ' + timedEvent.getProgress().toString().substr(0, 4));
        if(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.spacebar)){
            
            this.plantTree();
           
        }
    }
    
    plantTree(){
        var tree = new Tree(this).setScale(.2);
        
    }
}
```

This is the tree class:

```
class Tree extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite{
    constructor(scene,place){
        var x = scene.duck.x;
        var y = scene.duck.y;
        
        
        super(scene,x,y, "tree");
        scene.add.existing(this);
    }
    
    update(){
        this.destroy();
    }
   
}
```

I'm fairly new to Phaser. Pls let me know if you know the answer to how to instantiate trees in the game initially and how to fix the error with onEvent. Thanks.

Error is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: onEvent is not defined
    at Scene2.create (Scene2.js:44)
    at initialize.create (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.bootScene (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.start (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.processQueue (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.update (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.step (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.step (phaser.min.js:1)
    at e (phaser.min.js:1)
```

Comment: Hi can you also post the error you get from onEvent function?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: onEvent is not defined
    at Scene2.create (Scene2.js:44)
    at initialize.create (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.bootScene (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.start (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.processQueue (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.update (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.step (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.step (phaser.min.js:1)
    at e (phaser.min.js:1)

Comment: Okey first, it should the `callback: this.onEvent`

Comment: Second, i don't think that `tree.update` functions doesn't need to called as far as i know those are calling by game it self

Comment: 3.  if you call destroy on update method those are gonna destroyed right away and you won't be able see those at all

Comment: How can I make it not be destroyed right away? I thought because of the timer event, the tree would be there for at least a few seconds before it gets destroyed?

Comment: No no those are gonna destroyed directly cause you are calling `tree.update()` right array,  do you actually have a github page or smt i would like to help but it's gonna be really hard from here :D

Comment: I have a git hub but I dont post stuff there lol

Comment: Its bananachicken23

Comment: I see just make a private repo and add me as collabrator and then we can go from there?

Comment: What is your user for github?

Comment: https://github.com/halilcakar :)

Comment: I have added you :D

Comment: DM me twitter @hcakar1992